# Why WordPress update is not working on a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, post

I have used this code to update a post `$x = wp_update_post($post);` But it is not updating any information at all. Following is the content of the $post array that has been sent to the function. Here it is returning 582 thus it is successful. I don't know is there any other way to do this? There are some custom post meta and the post type is photo a custom one.

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 582
    [upload_title] => Flower Warriors
    [upload_desc] => Aenean condimentum massa id leo ullamcorper 
    [upload_keywords] => Blog, Demo, Flower, Images
    [upload_price] => 58
    [extra_categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 10
            [3] => 18
            [4] => 19
            [5] => 23
        )

    [property_release] => 2
    [release_info] => Tinterdum lacus eget hendrerit? Quisque a turpis sit amet est consequat vestibulum.
    [large_price] => 39
    [medium_price] => 18
    [small_price] => 14
)
```

Answer (score 0):

wp_update_post doesn't update custom fields. For those you'd need to do something like:

add_post_meta($id, 'upload_title', 'Flower Warriors', true) or update_post_meta($id, 'upload_title', 'Flower Warriors');

Easiest way is to add the custom fields to a separate variable and run a foreach loop on it.

```
//$id is the ID of the post you're updating
foreach ($cf as $k => $v) :
    add_post_meta($id, $k, $v, true) or update_post_meta($id, $k, $v);
endforeach;
```